# How do I quit application written in Clojure Seesaw?

Tags: user-interface, clojure, seesaw

I am aware of

```
(frame
     :title "Example"
     :on-close :exit)
```

but what I am supposed to do if I want to do some custom action after selecting Quit in the menu?

```
(fn [e] (System/exit 0) )
```

didn't work.

### Edit 1

Oops, (fn [e] (System/exit 0) ) works, provided you do

```
:listen [:action ...
```

instead of :listen [:mouse-clicked..

Sorry for not noticing that before.